# How can i change background and text color in android webview internet pages?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I want to change only background and text colors.Not images or videos. Actually i want to make changes like dark backgrounds changer add-on in firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dark-backgrounds-switcher/

Answer (score 0):

Guys i found a solution myself :) But i am expecting better solutions from you...
By applying this javascript to webview i achieved my goal

`String nightmodejs="var elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName(\"*\");"
            +"for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {"
            +"elements[i].style.color = \"#E8E8E8\"; "
            +"elements[i].style.backgroundColor=\"black\";"
            +"elements[i].style.backgroundImage=\"none\";"
            +"}"
            +" document.body.style.backgroundColor = \"black\";";`